# Mercurial, pulling a single branch

Tags: mercurial

I have two Mercurial repos C1 and C2 which both derived from the same parent P some time ago but have since had separate lines of development.  In addition, in C2, there is a named branch B2 which happened since the diversion.  I want to pull only branch B2 into C1, which I can easily do with hg pull C2 --branch B2.

Now B2 branches off of some points in the default branch of the C2 repo.  So those default changesets from C2 get pulled over into C1 even though I am only trying to pull branch B2.  (I can understand that since they are ancestors of the B2 changesets).

After the above pull, I will have two heads on the default branch of C1, the original head and the head composed of those default changesets that got pulled over as a result of pulling B2 over.  I want to leave the default branch of C1 unchanged, otherwise I have two heads, keep getting told that updates "cross branches" and telling me I have to merge.  (I will be pulling new default branch things into C1 from other external repos going forward).

How can I do the above so that I do not have two heads on default?

Comment: Won't pulling B2 into C1 automatically create B2's branch in C1 at the same point as it is in C2?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the problem, am I right in thinking you have something like this?

```
@  4[tip]:1   439255c536ee   2013-01-25 10:42 +0000   rob
|    More changes on original default branch
|
|   o  3   379f384c1d73   2013-01-25 10:41 +0000   rob
|   |   Changes on named branch B2
|  /
| o  2:0   d225da266931   2013-01-25 10:40 +0000   rob
| |    Changes on cloned default
| |
o |  1   7088660d3ba6   2013-01-25 10:41 +0000   rob
|/     Changes on original default branch
|
o  0   a02a921256b3   2013-01-25 10:39 +0000   rob
     Project Start
```

The problem you're describing is that while you want to keep the `B2` branch, you don't want the two heads on `default`:

```
$ hg heads default --style=compact
4[tip]:1   439255c536ee   2013-01-25 10:42 +0000   rob
  More changes on original default branch

2:0   d225da266931   2013-01-25 10:40 +0000   rob
  Changes on cloned default
```

I can see two possibilities to "fix" this.  One is simply to close the "cloned" default branch (at least in your repo):

```
$ hg update 2
$ hg commit -m "Closing cloned default" --close-branch
$ hg heads default --style=compact
4[tip]:1   439255c536ee   2013-01-25 10:42 +0000   rob
  More changes on original default branch
```

This would mean that if you issue an `hg update default`, it *shouldn't* be ambiguous, which I guess is part of the problem.

An alternative would be to do a "[null merge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge)" from the other default branch:

```
$ hg update
$ hg -y merge --tool=internal:fail 2
$ hg revert --all --rev .
$ hg resolve -a -m
$ hg commit -m "Merged cloned default"
```

The main difference in these approaches is that using the `--close-branch` option, you can still see the extra head when you use `hg heads -c`... it is still a head, but it simply has a flag set in the metadata to say it's closed.  You can still update to the closed branch, and even commit changes to it.  Doing a merge you won't see the head at all, as it will not longer be a head.

Both of these methods mean that you can still pull changes to the B2 branch - however, if in the repo you're pulling from they make changes on default and merge those into B2 (often used when bugfixing, etc), you will hit the same problem later on, and have to repeat the above.

I hope that makes sense.  Of course, if you later push to another repo, you will push the closed/merged changesets too.  It would be wise to clone your repo and try these approaches locally to check if that's what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work and is much simpler than the rebasing things that I was trying. I hadn't realized you can close an un-named branch, very useful.   I noticed when I finally pushed to the master repo (using push --new-branch), there was still a message that push creates new remote head, but I used -f and had no problems with future hg updates, etc.

Comment: You shouldn't get the "push creates a new remote head" if you use the null-merge option. However, the problem with creating a new remote head is that it creates an ambiguity - "what should I update to?". So if you've closed the branch, it removes that ambiguity anyway.